# Load specific amount from Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a chat application that holds the messages in Cloud FireStore.
My problem is that the application loads all of the messages when opening the chat rooms.

What I want is for it to only load the 50 latest messages and allow for loading additional chats if scrolling up on the FlatList. I am developing in React Native.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = firestore()
            .collection('message')
            .doc(props.chat.key)
            .collection('messages')
            .orderBy("msgDate", "desc")
            .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                const tempMessage = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                    tempMessage.push({
                        ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                        key: documentSnapshot.id,
                    });
                });

                setMessage(tempMessage);
            });

        // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
        return () => subscriber();
    }, []);


<FlatList
            inverted
            data={message}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <MessageItem msgItem={item} />
            )}
        />
```

Edit: Figured out that I could use .Limit(50) To only load 50 documents. Still working on the refresh when scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for limiting your data.
Here is the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) on ordering and limiting your firestore data.

You can add a condition in your query to load only last 20-30 messages.
orderBy will also be useful here as you want to fetch the latest messages. You can orderBy on created time of your messages to get latest messages.

Comment: Thank you, found out that .Limit(50) was the answer I needed for only getting a specific amount. Now I just need to figure out the rest. :) 

Would upvote you, but seems that I lack the required reputation.. :/